# Serilog - AppSettings for Application name

Tags: .net, serilog, appsettings, seq-logging

I am trying to read the application name from the App.Config. This is `net461` console app. I have added the [Serilog.Settings.AppSettings](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/AppSettings) package. And also added the following serilog configs on App.Config

```
<add key="serilog:properties:Application" value="My App"/>
<add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Debug" />
<add key="serilog:minimum-level:override:Microsoft" value="Debug" />
<add key="serilog:enrich:FromLogContext"/>
<add key="serilog:enrich:WithMachineName"/>
<add key="serilog:enrich:WithProcessId"/>
<add key="serilog:using:Seq" value="Serilog.Sinks.Seq"/>
<add key="serilog:write-to:Seq.serverUrl" value="http://localhost:5341" />
<add key="serilog:using:Console" value="Serilog.Sinks.Console" />
<add key="serilog:write-to:Console"/>
```

But the application name is not displaying on [Seq](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-seq). However, I have added the following settings on `appsettings.json` for a .netcore2 project, this works as expected

```
"Serilog": {
  "Properties": {
    "Application": "Another app"
  }
}
```

What is missing?

Comment: My company has found that adding the application name is easier to do within Seq by adding an applied property to your API key. Of course, this only affects Seq, so if you have other sinks you may still want to specify  the application name within the application. We also add additional properties such as environment and sub-application that make it easier to filter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
<add key="serilog:enrich:with-property:Application" value="My App" />
```

(Rather than `"serilog:properties...`)